# Assistance regarding finding the duplicate in an Excel sheet

Tags: c#, exception, datatable, casting, runtime

Below is code to find the duplicate in an Excel sheet

DataTable dtExcel

```
        //Find Excel Duplicates
        var excelDuplicates = dtExcel.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(dr => dr.Field<string>("Value"))
            .Where(gr => gr.Count() > 1)
            .Select(gr => Convert.ToString(gr.First()["Value"]))
            .ToList();
```

I don't have "Value" as column in my excel sheet , in fact I don't have any header.
so I need to find duplicate in a excel with no header/column name
I need to find duplicate in the first column

I tried using dr.Field(string)(dr[0]))  but it didn't help , since it threw error as System.InvalidCastException: **'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'**.'

(bascially I am tryng to overload dr.field with int..

**can somebody help me with this?**

Answer (score 0):

May be You can use 3rd pary Libraries like "ClosedXML"

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = workbook.Worksheet("sheetName");
```

Then iterate through all data in for loop geting and compareing values like

```
var valueToCompare=  ws.Row(i).Cell(j).GetString();
```

Or if You have to compare formula values(results) You can use smthing like using 'Spire.Xls' the idea is the same:

```
 Workbook wb = new Workbook();
 wb.LoadFromFile("file path");
 Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

var valueToCompare=ws.Range["A1"].FormulaValue;
```

Using this libraries You can recive diferent type of data from excel